# Don't apply :hover when hovering on :before element

Tags: html, css

I want to apply some styles to the :before pseudo-element when hovering the element, but not when hovering the :before element itself. Is it possible?

html:

```
<div class="box">Hover this to get green</div>
```

css:

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box:before {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  content: "Hovering this should not make it green";
}

.box:hover:before {
  color: green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61kwo8r6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set `pointer-events: none` on pseudo element which is also going to remove hover event from it.

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box:before {
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  content: "Hovering this should not make it green";
}
.box:hover:before {
  color: green;
}
.box:before {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Hover this to get green</div>
```